# How can I get equivalent negate expression in google RE2

Tags: regex, go, re2

As google re2 is not supporting negate look forward/behind how can I convert below Perl regex to re2?

```
(?=(\/customer*))(^((?!\/customer\/v2).)*$)
```

This regex should allow uri/s `/customer/whatever` but not `/customer/v2`

Answer (score 0):

```
(\/customer\/(?:[^v\s]\S?|\S[^2\s?])+)$
```

I'm not sure it is the best way, but its allowed results are the same as your pattern's allowed results.

- My pattern's demo: https://regex101.com/r/xTO7A8/2
- Your pattern's demo: https://regex101.com/r/PZjhLs/2

Group 1:

- `[^v\s]` => A character which is not "v" or "whitespace".
- `[^v\s]\S` => A character which is not "v" or "whitespace" followed by non-whitespace character.
- `[^v\s]\S?` => A character which is not "v" or "whitespace" followed by zero or one non-whitespace character.

Group 2:

- `[^2\s?]` => A character which is not "2" or "whitespace".
- `\S[^2\s?]` => A non-whitespace character followed by "2" or "whitespace" character.
- `[^v\s]\S?` => A character which is not "v" or "white space", followed by zero or one non-whitespace character.

When we combine groups with or symbol ("|"), it means the string after the "/customer/" must not start with "v2".